# How to receive all cookies on dynamic website

Tags: python, cookies, request, web-scraping

I'm trying to create a Python script which needs all cookies from website with dynamic page loading (using javascript). How to do it? Urllib requests and even mechanize are not working in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recreate the AJAX calls in Python or use a headless browser like [Ghost](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/).